# Order by both ASC and DESC at a time in single CASE WHEN statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case, case-when

I have this stored procedure called `BlogsPostForDefault`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BlogsPostForDefault]                    
    @RowID int,                  
    @SORTBY nvarchar(50)                    
AS                    
BEGIN                    
    DECLARE @PageSize INT = 10                   
    DECLARE @PostIds TABLE(RowID INT, PostID INT, TotalViews INT)

    INSERT INTO @postIds (RowId, PostID, totalViews)                  
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE @sortBy WHEN 'date' THEN CP.PostDate END DESC, <-- **adding one more DESC CP.SortOrder here, HOW?**                   
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'views' THEN IsNull(MAVC.ViewCount,CP.TotalViews) END DESC), 
            CP.PostID, 
            ISNULL(MAVC.ViewCount, CP.TotalViews) AS TotalViews
        FROM 
            CS_Posts CP (NOLOCK)                    
        INNER JOIN 
            cs_Threads CT (NOLOCK) ON CP.ThreadID = CT.ThreadID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            PostViewCount MAVC (NOLOCK) ON CP.PostID = MAVC.PostID
        WHERE 
            CP.SectionID = 94                    
            AND CP.isapproved = 1                    
            AND cp.PostDate <= GETDATE()                    
            AND CP.PostLevel = 1 

    SELECT 
        T.RowId, T.PostID, T.TotalViews,
        prd.FinalThumbnailImage AS Thumbnail, CP.Subject,
        SUBSTRING(CP.Body,0,1000) as Body,
        DATENAME(mm, CP.PostDate)+ ' ' + CONVERT( varchar(2),datepart (dd, CP.PostDate)) + ', '+ CONVERT( varchar(4),datepart(year, CP.PostDate)) as PostDate, 
        ISNULL(NULLIF(prd.ALT, ''), 
        CP.Subject) AS ALT                    
    FROM 
        @postIds T                     
    INNER JOIN 
        CS_Posts CP (NOLOCK) ON T.PostID = CP.PostID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Mercola_PostRelatedData prd (NOLOCK) ON T.PostID = prd.PostID
    WHERE 
        T.RowID > @RowID AND T.RowID <= @RowID + @PageSize                  
    ORDER BY
        T.RowID   
END
```

When I execute the above stored procedure with

```
Exec [BlogsPostForDefault] 13000, 'date'
```

I want it to be sorted by `CP.PostDate DESC` as well as `CP.SortOrder DESC`

I tried to add this but returns an error.

Current output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

How should I do it, please help..!!

Comment: Note that sorting on a case can eat performance, because the db may not be able to plan the execution very well.  Also, always query date ranges as exclusive upper-bound (`<`), not inclusive.

Comment: "returns an error" - ah, yes. An error. I *wish* errors contained specific messages that gave us clues about what the problem was. Oh wait, they do. So why not *tell us* what the error message was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the 2nd order as a 2nd case when on the same condition:

```
ORDER BY CASE @sortBy WHEN 'date' THEN CP.PostDate END DESC,
    CASE @sortBy WHEN 'date' THEN CP.SortOrder END DESC,
    CASE @sortBy WHEN 'views' THEN IsNull(MAVC.ViewCount,CP.TotalViews) END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b0ad/7/0